# How to get the average of a time frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large CSV file as below:

```
                     dd  hh  v.amm  v.alc  v.no2  v.cmo   aqi
t                                                            
2018-11-03 00:00:00   3   0  0.390  0.490  1.280  1.760 2.560
2018-11-03 00:01:00   3   0  0.390  0.490  1.280  1.760 2.560
2018-11-03 00:02:00   3   0  0.380  0.460  1.300  1.610 2.500
2018-11-03 00:03:00   3   0  0.380  0.450  1.310  1.600 2.490
...
2018-11-28 23:56:00  28  23  0.670  0.560  1.100  1.870 2.940
2018-11-28 23:57:00  28  23  0.660  0.570  1.100  1.990 2.950
2018-11-28 23:58:00  28  23  0.660  0.570  1.100  1.990 2.950
2018-11-28 23:59:00  28  23  0.650  0.530  1.130  1.880 2.870

[37440 rows x 7 columns]
```

I'd like to take the average of 60 minutes to obtain hourly data. The final data would look something like this:

```
                     dd  hh  v.amm  v.alc  v.no2  v.cmo   aqi
t                                                            
2018-11-03 00:00:00   3   0  0.390  0.490  1.280  1.760 2.560
2018-11-03 01:00:00   3   1  0.390  0.490  1.280  1.760 2.560
2018-11-03 02:00:00   3   2  0.380  0.460  1.300  1.610 2.500
2018-11-03 03:00:00   3   3  0.380  0.450  1.310  1.600 2.490
```

I tried

```
print (df['v.amm'].resample('60Min').mean())

t
2018-11-03 00:00:00   0.357
2018-11-03 01:00:00   0.354
2018-11-03 02:00:00   0.369
2018-11-03 03:00:00   0.384
```

but I don't think it's efficient as it only prints one specific column at a time, without heading as well.

Comment: what happens when you do `df.resample('60Min').mean()`?

Comment: Oh thanks. that works! sorry I'm new to coding.